# How to print from android device with shared printer?

Tags: android, printing, device

I have a printer no wifi and bluetooth, it connected with computer via USB. May I print something from android device???

Answer (score 1):

If you download Chrome and add the printer to Google Cloud Print on the Google account you use on your Android device, you should be able to print things, assuming you're running a supported OS and using an app that supports printing.

For more info: http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. But I want to ask you one more thing: If my printer added google clound print, may I create project to print without download an another app???